# Possible to use conditional execution in Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Is it possible to ask fabric to perform actions conditionally? This should be fairly trivial, because it's "just Python", but I'm not 100% sure how to run commands and capture their return code or output.

As an example, how would I have behaviour that is conditional on the value of an environment variable in the host?

Comment: What do you have now?  What have you tried?

Comment: So far I've tried glaring angrily at my computer monitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
@hosts('host.example.com')
def task():
    if run('echo $SOME_VAR') == 'some value':
        run('some_other_command.sh')
```

Comment: I didn't realise that `run` returns STDOUT. Excellent.

Comment: I also opened https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/496 since it seems weird Fabric doesn't have a nice `envvar('SOME_VAR')` command. We'll see if the maintainer thinks it's worthy to implement something like that.